# (Python) Where to get the historical VIX data except from FRED?

Tags: python-3.x

I can use the following code to get the historical data VIX from FRED. But the update time is less than 20 minutes before the market open. It is a little bit too late (Updated: 8:41 AM CDT). The update time from CBOE is much earlier. I wonder how to get them from CBOE (not using the fetch_csv)?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1)

## CBOE Volatility Index: VIX
vix = web.DataReader("VIXCLS", "fred", start)
print(len(vix))
print(vix.tail())
print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now finally I've found the better solution to my question. I get the VIX from Quandl. My code look as below. Hope this will also help the other.

```
import quandl

vix = quandl.get("CBOE/VIX")
vix_close = vix['VIX Close']
print("VIX:\n%s" %vix_close[-15:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that Quandl no longer publishes this, you can get it from CBOE directly [futures history] https://www.cboe.com/us/futures/market_statistics/historical_data/ and  [index history] https://www.cboe.com/tradable_products/vix/vix_historical_data/.

[vix_utils](https://pypi.org/project/vix_utils/) provides both a command line program (for people who use R, excel etc)  and Python API that downloads the data from CBOE.